# Magento 2.2.6: How to define max width page?

Tags: css, magento2.2.6

I need the page to be seen with the maximum possible length

**Class:**

[image]

What do I need to replace?

Comment: could you please share URL ?

Comment: This is in localhost, the home page. What do you need?

Answer (score 0):

1) app\design\frontend\Tvap\tvap-custom\web\css\source Open _layout.less file.

```
/*.breadcrumbs,*/
.page-header .header.panel,
.header.content,
.page-wrapper > .widget,
.page-wrapper > .page-bottom,
.block.category.event,
.top-container,
.page-main,
.configurable-product-container, 
.simple-product-container,
.bundle-product-container {   
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: @layout__max-width;
    padding-left: @layout-indent__width;
    padding-right: @layout-indent__width;
    width: auto;
}
```

**Comment class which you need to full width.**

2) add your custom css for that.

.breadcrumbs {
     width: 100%; 
}